# Convert 'hhmm' int to proper format

Tags: python, pandas, time

i'm relatively new to Python

I have a column of data which represents time of the day - but in an integer format *hhmm* - i.e. 1230, 1559.

I understand that this should be converted to a correct time format so that it can be used correctly.

I've spent a while googling for an answer but I haven't found a definitive solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need datetimes, also are necessary `date`s by function [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), for times add [`dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html).

Another solution is convert values to [timedeltas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) - but is necessary format `HH:MM:SS`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[1230,1559]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%H%M')
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%H%M').dt.time

s = df['col'].astype(str)
df['td'] = pd.to_timedelta(s.str[:2] + ':' + s.str[2:] + ':00')
print (df)
    col                date      time       td
0  1230 1900-01-01 12:30:00  12:30:00 12:30:00
1  1559 1900-01-01 15:59:00  15:59:00 15:59:00

print (df.dtypes)
col               int64
date     datetime64[ns]
time             object
td      timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: So the column would have to have a 'dummy' date as well as the time?

Comment: @BenG - exactly, if need datetimes, not exist only times with no dates

Comment: @BenG you can drop the 'dummy' date column after extracting the time

Comment: I'm not sure if I can ask another question here - but is there a simple way to filter this (time) column based on values?

Comment: @BenG - Do you think something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871) ?

Comment: I understand how basic filtering works with pandas (.loc/.iloc etc). However this format type is new to me. I just want to create a new column that has the values 'morning', 'afternoon' and 'evening' dependent on the values in the time column.

Comment: But my data is in datetime.time format and not datetime?

Comment: @BenG - So use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%H%M').dt.hour` - need datetimes